# How to dynamically import jar on Runtime. tools.jar

Tags: java

I am trying to import the `tools.jar` from Java's JDK yet I am getting an `InstantiationException` whenever I attempt to create a `newInstance` of a class from the library.

My code so far:

```
File toolsLib = new File("myjdk/lib/tools.jar");
URLClassLoader myClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { toolsLib.toURL() }, System.class.getClassLoader());
Class vmClass = myClassLoader.loadClass("com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine");
vmClass.newInstance(); //This is where I get an InstantiationException
```

This is all done within a seperate thread from my main program.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor of `com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine` has the modifier protected and takes two arguments. That is why it is not possible to create a new instance using `newIntance()`.

> Class.newInstance() will only succeed if the constructor is has zero
>   arguments and is already accessible.

However there are static `attach` methods defined on [VirtualMachine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html), that can be used to get an instance.

Take also a look at Oracle's documentation on [class instantiation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html).